# How do i use a ready VTF weapon skin in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I would like to download a ready VTF weapon skin and use that skin for my weapons. I would like also other people to be able to see it.

I don't want to create weapon skins from scratch and submit them through `workbench`, but rather to use skins that other people have made available for public use.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you cannot use WORKSHOP skins they way you would want (+ I would too!).The plan is that someday it will happen , or that Valve will be verifying some of these skins and they will be getting released gradually.
This is the case because if there was no restriction we would get nazi symbols and stuff like that on every weapon in the first hour.

You might be able to DL it and see it ONLY for YOURSELF but I am not sure if so and how.
**But for sure you cannot use it so others can see it too etc..For now.**

GAME ON.

Comment: So then how do I see other people's colorful weapons?

Comment: @mgPePe The idea is that you can purchase weapon skins that you like and show them off in the game. Some are found as drops, some are opened from cases, and etc. It's a way to allow the community of players and content creators to reward each other.

Comment: @Decency, "content creators" is the key term. So I can create weapon skins myself?

Comment: @mgPePe Yes, but they have to be approved through the workshop if you want them to be treated like other skins that are out there. It is quite the competition: http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/about/?appid=730